# elements of variable sizes in the same space

Tags: html, css

I have two elements that have variable width, and must share the same space in a div

I created an example in this link:
http://jsfiddle.net/zWVVN/

- #test-1: Should look like.
- #test-2: Problem situation.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Can you clarify?

Comment: I want to put two elements in the same line, so that they automatically use all the space

Answer (score 0):

Hi you define hr float left that conditions you must define width of all hr those give to float as like this

**Css**

```
#teste1, #teste2 {
    width: 300px; }
hr {
    border: 1px solid green;
    background: red;
    height: 25px;
    float: left;
    width:200px;
}
h2 {
    float: right;}

#teste1 hr{
    width: 230px;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="teste1">
    <hr>
    <h2>conteudo</h2>
</div>



    <div id="teste2">
        <hr>
        <h2>conteudo</h2>
    </div>
​
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/3e6bd/2/

Comment: Hey @azad, the width of <hr> is dynamic, can not set a value. I.e. 230px or 200px.

Answer (score 0):

If you want both divs to take up the whole space and do not want to wrap text down, then why have u set the width for both the divs to 300px. Remove the width assigned to both the divs and make both HR to float left.

```
#teste1, #teste2 {
    //this class not needed
}
hr {
    border: 0;
    background: red;
    height: 5px;
    float: left;
}
h2 {
    float: left;
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/3e6bd/3/